# Save items from JComboBox to text file

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox (cmbCourse) that uses the Scanner class to add items ('Science', 'Psychology', 'Law') from a text file. Now I want to create an if statement that gets the selected item from the comboBox but I'm having trouble, it should be something like this:

```
if(cmbCourse.getSelectedItem() == Science) {
...
}
```

I get an error saying that 'Science' can't be resolved to a variable. How do I access the items that come from the text file and compare them to the items from the comboBox?

Comment: I think this needs to be `if(cmbCourse.getSelectedItem() == 'Science') {` You need quotes around Science

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are adding strings to the combobox, getSelectedItem should return a string.  However, it returns said string as an object.  The comparison should work anyway, just good to know.

It's important to note that in Java, strings do NOT compare correctly using ==, as this is object equals.  You MUST use .equals() for correct string comparison.  Also, null check in case nothing is selected.

```
if( cmbCourse.getSelectedItem() != null && cmbCourse.getSelectedItem().equals( "Science" )
{
  // do stuff
}
```